Can we reopen the question "Which is the correct idiom — 'When worst comes to worst' or 'When worse comes to worst'?"
The question Which is the correct idiom – "When worst comes to worst" or "When worse comes to worst"? was posted in early 2014, near the end of an era when people commonly posted questions at EL&U without showing the results of any independent research they may have done before posting those questions.
About four and a half years later, near the height of the site participants' zeal to close questions that didn't show research, this question was closed. I didn't (and don't) think that closure was justified, considering that (1) the question had been open and uncontroversially live on the site for more than four years, (2) the question had drawn (and continues to draw) strong interest from site visitors, with more than 32,700 views as I write this, and (3) the trigger for closing it seems not to have been that the question was suddenly and retrospectively offensive to site participants, but that the question had drawn two new answers (including one by me) that raised its profile.
Now that "closed for lack of research" is no longer a standard one-click close reason at EL&U, it seems particularly unfortunate that a question asked before that close reason came into full force should be prevented from accepting new answers because it anachronistically fell victim to that rationale for closure.
Please consider either voting to reopen the question or making an argument here on EL&U Meta that keeping the question closed is, on balance, better for the site. Thanks!

It's been reopened, though not by my hand.
For the record, while dictionaries may appear to answer this, mine only lists the forms with worst/worst, not worse/worst. The extra detail given in the answers is definitely worth it.
